# Bot Framework Conversation Update using C#

Tags: c#, botframework

When i am testing my bot into Webchat channel, then getting welcome reply two times instead of one.

i am using conversation update mechanism to send welcome response in case of new member added or fresh conversation.

can you please tell what i am missing?

thanks in advance,

Sanjeev

Answer (score 1):

It must be displaying the messaging also when BOT is added to the conversation.
You need to add a check if the member added to the conversation isn't BOT itself.

```
private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
{
    if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
    {
        // Implement user deletion here
        // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
    {
        // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
        // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
        // Not available in all channels

        // Note: Add introduction here:
        IConversationUpdateActivity update = message;
        var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials());
        if (update.MembersAdded != null && update.MembersAdded.Any())
        {
            foreach (var newMember in update.MembersAdded)
            {
                if (newMember.Id != message.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    var reply = message.CreateReply();
                    reply.Text = $"Welcome {newMember.Name}!";
                    client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
    {
        // Handle add/remove from contact lists
        // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
    {
        // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
    {
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is how you would do it.

You can get more detail at this link: http://www.davidezordan.net/blog/?p=8119